# Does OpenStack Heat support YAML short form?

Tags: openstack, openstack-heat

Does OpenStack Heat support YAML short form? For example, !Select instead of Fn::Select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this latest Heat Documentation: https://docs.openstack.org/heat/latest/template_guide/hot_spec.html#template-structure

I don't think it supports the short form. The best way to check is to go to the Heat IRC (#openstack-heat) and ask its core developers.

HTH.